# Selecting only those that have a duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find rows that have the same `fnumber` and `fname`

I can return the ones that are duplicated using this query but it only gives me the duplicates. I want to return both the duplicate row and the original.

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT fnumber, findex,fname,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY fnumber ORDER BY fnumber)
   FROM dbo.coolTableBro
   where fnumber like '014%'
)
select * FROM CTE where RN > 1
```

Query output:

```
fnumber findex  fname   RN
01474   220569  MT1     2
01475   220570  MT1     2
01476   220571  MT1     2
01477   220572  MT1     2
01478   220573  MT1     2
01479   220574  MT1     2
01480   220575  MT1     2
01481   220576  MT1     2
```

Desired output:

```
fnumber findex  fname   RN
01474   220532  MT1     1
01474   220569  MT1     2
01475   220533  MT1     1
01475   220570  MT1     2
01476   220534  MT1     1
01476   220571  MT1     2
01477   220535  MT1     1
01477   220572  MT1     2
01478   220536  MT1     1
01478   220573  MT1     2
01479   220537  MT1     1
01479   220574  MT1     2
01480   220538  MT1     1
01480   220575  MT1     2
01481   220539  MT1     1
01481   220576  MT1     2
```

If I change the where clause I also get several rows that are not duplicate. I kind of need something like this pseudo statement, which obviously isn't valid SQL

`select fnumber,findex,fname from coolTableBro where fnumber and fname are the same in at least two rows and fnumber starts with 014`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `COUNT`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT fnumber, findex,fname,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY fnumber ORDER BY fnumber),
       CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fnumber)
   FROM dbo.coolTableBro
   where fnumber like '014%'
)
select * FROM CTE where CNT > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `count(*)` instead of `row_number()`:

```
with cte as (
      select fnumber, findex, fname,
             count(*) over (partition by fnumber) as cnt
      from dbo.coolTableBro
      where fnumber like '014%'
)
select * 
from cte
where cnt > 1;
```

In terms of performance, `exists` is often better:

```
select tb.*
from dbo.coolTableBro tb
where tb.fnumber like '014%' and
      exists (select 1
              from dbo.coolTableBro tb2
              where tb2.fnumber = tb.fnumber and tb2.findex <> tb.findex
             );
```

This is particularly true if you have an index on `(fnumber, findex)`.